# The CSS is not working for on my zend framwork

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework, it is a great framework. But I have seen an unexpected error with zend framework. That I want to share with you guys.
The problem is that, locally my css is working fine, but it is not working with zend framework.

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/bootstrap.css') ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/bootstrap-theme.css') ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') ?>
```

Above is the installation that I did. I used base URL as will.
need you kind suggestions.
Regards

Comment: It's not your current problem, but pay attention: you load 2 files not needed. Load only the "min" files, which means "minimized". /css/bootstrap.css and css/bootstrap.min.css contains exactly same data...

Comment: I did that, but still the same problem. and the style.css file is not editable. I am trying to edit it with Mozilla firebug, or Chrome elements. but it is contain a line on it, and that is it.

Comment: "It is not working" is not a valid problem description. If it was working you wouldn't be here. Tell us exactly what happens. Does no style get applied. Does the wrong style get applied.

Comment: The thing that I found after in one hour hard work, was css mixing problem. so the final conclusion of our research is that, it is good to use only one style.css file. It is not good to use more than one css file. we need to include all our css to only one file. I hope other will learn from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the [baseUrl()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) helper like this:

1. Your **css** directory must be in the **public** directory.
2. Regroup all append css with head link:

   ```
   <?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/bootstrap.css')
                          //->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/bootstrap.min.css')
                          ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/bootstrap-theme.css')
                          //->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
                          ;
   ```

   (As said Nicolas Henrard  in a comment, choose bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css)
3. Echo your CSS:

   ```
   echo $this->headLink(); ?>
   ```